# GWT: access a ListBox inside a Panel inside a Panel

Tags: gwt, casting, listbox, navigation, widget

I've got a panel, which contains a bunch of (multiselect) ListBoxes each inside their own panel, and I need to figure out what the selected values in the ListBoxes are. Going through the API, the only way I can see of doing this is (pseudocode):

```
for (Wigdet w : outerPanel)
  Panel innerPanel = (Panel) w;
  for (Widget s : innerPanel)  // only has the ListBox in it
    ListBox box = (ListBox) s;
    // do stuff with the ListBox to populate the list of selected options
```

The trouble is with the casting - eclipse doesn't complain and it compiles fine, but when run it produces a ClassCastException (on the first cast - I assume it would also have the same problem on the second, but since I can't get to it I can't say for sure)

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What does w.getClass() return at the point where the ClassCastException occurs? I mean use your debugger to stop at that point and put w.getClass().getName() in the watch list.

Comment: Check out the declarative layout with [UI Binder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html)...much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Apparently GWT inserts its own widgets into your panel, besides the ones you add yourself (so creating a Panel then adding a ListBox to in will result in more than just the one widget on iteration).

So to solve the problem, throw in an instanceof check before the casting

Comment: You should always do typechecking before casting the varible ;) (it doesn't even coast performance because if you cast something it does a typechecking anyway and if you do it befor casting it remebers that the typechecking already happend)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just declare them as instance variables?

Comment: because there are an awful lot of them. I could have thrown them in a list and passed them like that, but since I had just added them (and nothing else) to a Panel, I thought just pass that instead